# Does the Android bitmap have a minimum value?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

i have a 6x10 size image(width:6 height:10). my project uses this image.
but When i load an image with a bitmap, the size comes out as width:9 height:10.

I want a 6x10 dot image made of only white and black.
I want to use only pixels of the original image exactly 6x10.

EX)
if image[x][y] == 'black':
do something
else :
do something

Please somebody help me.

** I found a answer.
just add bitmap options.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources,id,options);
```

thank you!

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Phix ok i edited